# math.random return array function f

Tags: javascript, function

I'm not too familiar how I am supposed to create a math.random function. I'm still new to functions and when to use loops or how loops are used in the function. any advice will help. thank you.

1. Choose a data structure for this **list** of friends.
2. Write a comment in your code that explains why you chose this data structure.
3. Create a variable called `friends` and assign it to the data structure that you chose.
4. Take a look at the documentation for `Math.random` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random
5. Write a function that takes our `animals` array and returns a random element using `Math.random`

   ```
     var animal = {};
    animal.species = "bird";
    animal["name"] = "eagles";
    animal.noises = [];
    console.log(animal);


    //Steps 3
    var noises = [];
    noises[0] = "quack";
    noises.push("oink");
    noises[noises.length] = "bark";
    console.log(noises.length);
    console.log(noises.length-1);
    console.log(noises);

    //Step 4
    animal.noises = noises;
    animal.noises.push("meow");
    console.log(animal);

    //Step 6
    var animals = [];
    animals.push("animal");
    vconsole.log(animals);

    var duck = { 
   species: 'duck', 
   name: 'Jerome', 
   noises: ['quack', 'honk', 'sneeze', 'woosh'] };

    animals.push(duck);

    console.log(animals);

    var coco = { 
   species: 'dog', 
   name: 'bob', 
   noises: ['high', 'low'] };
    var bubbles = { 
   species: 'cat', 
   name: 'jim', 
   noises: ['quiet', 'loud'] };


    animals.push(coco, bubbles);
    console.log(animals);

    //Step 7
   ```

Comment: Is it a homework? You tried anything?

Comment: have you looked at the random function of `Math`?

Comment: The random function won't return an integer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Remember we are not a free coding service ;)

Answer (score -1):

Math.random() is getting you halfway there! You only need to round it down to an integer while expanding math.random()'s [0,1] output to [0, X], where X is your array's length!

if you have an array
animal = [lion, tiger, bear], with indexes [0,1,2], you can return a random animal like this:

randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length).

math.random() returns a value between 0 and 1, so you should multiply by 3 (array length) to give you a value between 0 and 3, then you should use Math.floor to force that randomNumber into an integer.

then the random animal is returned by animal[randomNumber]. Make sense?

Comment: You mean to say `randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)`

Comment: friends = [Math.floor(Math.random()*animals.length)];

this is going to make me sound dumb.
when i tried to return friends. i get an outside function error. thats what made me thought i needed to create a function.

Comment: hi @kenwin, i don't understand what "friends" is. Also, can you give us more information on the sample code you have uploaded? is it yours or was it given to you? how much of this assignment do you understand at all? I will help you but if you need to start at square one be honest!

Comment: Step 1 - Object Creation

 1. [ ] Create a variable named `animal` and assign it to an empty object.
 1. [ ] Using **dot notation** give `animal` a **property** named `species` with a value of any animal species.
 1. [ ] Using **bracket notation** give `animal` a **property** called `name` with a value of your animal`s name.
 1. [ ] Using either notation, give `animal` a **property** called `noises` with a value of empty array.

Comment: ## Step 2 - Array Creation
 1. Create a variable named `noises` and assign it to an empty array.
 2. Using **bracket notation** give `noises` it's first element. A string representing a sound your animal might make.
 3. Using an array function add another noise to the end of `noises`.
 4.  Look through the functions until you find the one that will place an element at the begining of the array.
 5.  Add an element to `noises` using this function.
 76  Using **bracket syntax** again, add another element to the end of `noises`.

Comment: Step 3 - A Collection of Animals
 1. [ ] Create a variable named `animals` and assign it to an empty array.
 2. [ ] `push` our `animal` that we created to `animals`.
 3. [ ] inspect `animals`. What does it look like?
 4.  Create a variable called `duck` and assign it to the data:
  - `{ species: 'duck', name: 'Jerome', noises: ['quack', 'honk', 'sneeze', 'woosh'] }`
 5. [ ] `push` `duck` to `animals`
 6. [ ] inspect `animals`. What does it look like?
 7.  Create two more animal objects each with a species, a name, and at least two sounds sounds and add each one of them to `animals.

Comment: i don't want a solution for this code, i'm trying to learn how to create codes and decide the correct method on doing so.

Comment: you haven't mentioned but i am assuming you're using Java?

Comment: javascript. i've been watching videos javascript functions and loops  for beginners.